# How to use one view for multiple routes in Ember

Tags: ember.js, view, routes, dry

I have a view in `views/posts/index.js`. And I have one route for list of posts and another for search engine. How can I use it in the second route, which is a search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a template `posts`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  <h3>{{ route }}</h3>
</script>
```

that you want to use for both `posts/index` and `posts/search`

You can override the `renderTemplate` method inside the route like this:

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return { route: "INDEX"};
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('posts', {
      into: 'application',
      controller: controller,
      model: model
    }); 
  }
});

App.PostsSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return { route: "SEARCH"};
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('posts', {
      into: 'application',
      controller: controller,
      model: model
    }); 
  }
});
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tiyofi/2/edit?html,js,output)